# Недалекий человек

Tags: фразеология

Как вы думаете, почему о человеке с ограниченным кругозором говорят, что он "недалекий"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Недалекого ума, так точнее.
Я думаю, это связано с его целями в жизни, они все ограничены его небольшими сегодняшними потребностями, а далеко вперед он не смотрит, никуда не стремится. Ему хватает того, что его окружает.

Comment: Можно и просто "недалёкий".
А вот то, что он сегодняшними потребьностями эивет и никуда не стримится - это немного не то. Другое качество. Он именно что не видит умом, не модет просчитать далёких результатов.

Answer (score 2):

"Недальновидный" было бы понятнее?
Это как одно из значений.

Смыл не в том, что он "далеко от кого-то", а в том что он не может просчитать, не видит умом далеких последствий, результатов, мыслит примитивными (ближайшими) категориями. Термин для свойства ума упростился и был перенесен на самого человека, такое в языке встречается (сравните: "любопытный" может значить либо "интересный", либо интересующийся").